# How do I import json file in React

Tags: json, reactjs, import

I need to import json data to run a react redux test. How do I import devMock.json into dashboard.test.js? Can I do it without installing dependency?

devMock.json

```
{
"data": {
    "0": 11,
    "1": 1
},
"polarity_freq": {
   "negative": 214,
   "positive": 220
},
"sentiments_freq": {
    "anger": 1,
    "fear": 0,
    "sad": 2,
    "joy": 11
 }
},
```

dashboard.test.js

```
import * as actions from '../actions/dashboardActions';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import expect from 'expect';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

describe('Dashboard action creators should be called', () => {

afterEach(() => {
  fetchMock.reset()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it changing your .json file to .js. Like that:

```
export {
"data": {
    "0": 11,
    "1": 1
},
"polarity_freq": {
   "negative": 214,
   "positive": 220
},
"sentiments_freq": {
    "anger": 1,
    "fear": 0,
    "sad": 2,
    "joy": 11
 }
};
```

After that, just import it like a normal .JS file.

```
import DevMock from './devMock.js';
```

Comment: It is pretty much easier to export .js file rather than .json file
Even if we tried above way, then we will get error as export does not specify, what to export.

Answer (score 2):

[Matheus'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8705708/matheus-pitz) answer is the right solution for your usecase, thought you have to specify the identifier of the object you're exporting, like this:

```
export const myJson = {
    "data": {
        "0": 11,
        "1": 1
    },
    "polarity_freq": {
        "negative": 214,
        "positive": 220
    },
    "sentiments_freq": {
        "anger": 1,
        "fear": 0,
        "sad": 2,
        "joy": 11
    }
};
```

And you can then import it like:

```
import { myJson } from "./myJson.js";
```

Furthermore, if you export just one object in your file, you can use a default export:

```
export default { ... }
```

And then import with the name you want:

```
import myAwesomeJson from "./myJson.js";
```

Answer (score 0):

This only worked for me when I imported the JSON file in the main App.js, and passed the json object to the child component in the props.

When I tried to import the json in the child component directly, the json object was only imported when the child file was imported into App, but not when the child component was rendered.