# How to Map a JSON File With IDs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I map and return the values "Title" in React, with a JSON file that contains an ID for each record? For example:

```
{

"id001": {
      "Title": "Title-1",
      "Year": "1990",
      "Rated": "PG-13"
      },

"id002": {
      "Title": "Title-2",
      "Year": "1999",
      "Rated": "PG-13"
      },
      
...

}
```

**Thank you so much!**

Comment: can you add your code rather than just the file?

Comment: `const titles = movies.map(movie => movie.Title)` will return an array of all titles. By the way, in JavaScript is "bad practice" to work with capitalized node names, you usually save them for Classes only. You want to use "camel case".

Comment: Thank you Caio! I'm using this Capitalization from an existing file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sxywu/filmflowers/master/movies.json)
By the way, this gives me [undefine] as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to import the json file first. some [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707019/how-do-i-import-json-file-in-react)

```js
const a = {

"id001": {
      "Title": "Title-1",
      "Year": "1990",
      "Rated": "PG-13"
      },

"id002": {
      "Title": "Title-2",
      "Year": "1999",
      "Rated": "PG-13"
      },
      

}

const titleArr = Object.keys(a).map(function(key, index) {
  return a[key].Title;
});

console.log(titleArr)
```

Comment: Thank you cmgchess! I had imported the json file using import.
This code helped me tremendously.
The json file had '''[ ]''' brackets at beginning and end of file, when removed, all worked fine.

Thank you all so much.